# Restoring the tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to restore a tensorflow model after it's trained. I know that I can use `tf.train.Saver` but the problem is with the restoring because I get confused with the names for `get_tensor_by_name`. Can anybody help me?
This is my graph:

```
x_hat = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, dim_img], name='input_img')
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, dim_img], name='target_img')

# dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

# input for PMLR
z_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, dim_z], name='latent_variable')

# network architecture
y, z, loss, neg_marginal_likelihood, KL_divergence = vae.autoencoder(x_hat, x, dim_img, dim_z, n_hidden,
                                                                                keep_prob)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you save a model you save 2 things: 1) the meta graph, that is a representation of the graph (all the TF symbols you've defined; and 2) the checkpoint which contains the actual Variable values (which are saved and restored by name).

When you restore you can restore one or both of those components. What you are describing is restoring both the meta graph AND the checkpoint data. In this case you need to look up the various operations and tensors you're interested by name, which can be confusing (especially if you didn't name your variables well, which you should always do).

```
# In this method you import the meta graph then restore
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('my-save-dir/my-model-10000.meta')
saver.restore(sess, 'my-save-dir/my-model-10000')
```

The other option to restoring (which I prefer mysefl) is to not load the meta graph at all. Instead just re-run the same code you originally used to create the graph (if you've done things well this will all be organized in one place). Then you only restore the checkpoint. This approach has the benefit that you can easily keep a reference to all the operations you'll need (such as cost, train_op, placeholders, etc).

```
# This method only performs the restor operation 
# assuming the graph is already constructure
saver.restore(sess, 'my-save-dir/my-model-10000')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Can you explain a bit more about the second approach?Let's assume I restore the checkpoint.. How can I test my new data on the pre-trained model that I restored?

Comment: You built your graph by calling a function like `build_graph()` which creates all the tensorflow objects. One of those objects might be called `logits`, the typical name for the output, another might be `accuracy` computing the accuracy of a batch. To evaluate these two tensors you'd just call `sess.run([logits, accuracy], feed_dict={X:your_data, y:your_labels})` assuming you have placeholders `X` and `y` also defined. It's the same as training except you're not evaluating the train_op, your're evaluating the operations you're interested in outputting.

Comment: Thanks. I know in general how to evaluate and run the code for test data. I was just curious if this is different if you restore your pre-trained model as you mentioned in the second option. I guess it's the same.

Comment: It is exactly the same regardless of how you restore the model.